# How can I get the page number of the table currently on iteration

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to determine which page number the current table in iteration is with the code below:

```
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", tableNo)
    End If

    resultRow = 4

    For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
        With .tables(tableStart)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                Next iCol
                Cells(resultRow, 4) = pageNumber
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next iRow
        End With
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next tableStart
End With
```

I've research a way and found this

```
oTable.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

I tried to use it by doing

```
pageNumber = .Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

but apparently its not working because im not actually looping through activeobjects. its basically:

```
wdDoc.tables(1-N).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber);
```

which is not working, error on wdActiveEndPageNumber,

is there a way to get the page number?

Comment: What do you mean by 1-N. You are using VBA, no need for a ';' at the end of the line.

Comment: 1-N will be an integer variable

Comment: If you are writing code from within Excel then wdActivePageNumber will be interpreted as zero because excel a has no knowledge of Word enumerations.  Therefore you need to find the enumeration used for .information in Word zand substitute the long value corresponding to the enumeration value of  wdActivePageNumber.